# Selenium IDE get stuck in popup window javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, selenium

I am brand new to selenium ide using fire fox. I am trying to test a calender which is a popup html and i read a lot of things and mostly said that I need to write  "javascrtip select element ..." command but no matter how many times I tried I cant get it working .  here is the site http://demo.owncloud.org/index.php/apps/calendar . when you click on the calender date there is a popup that comes in order for me to chose a date and hours and stuff. I dont know how you get the popup working in the selenium. I dont even know how you would understand if it is an ajax or javascript 
here is some part of the code that is about choosing calender

```
<div id="notification" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="controls">
    <form id="view">
        <input type="button" value="Week" id="oneweekview_radio" original-title="">
        <input type="button" value="Month" id="onemonthview_radio" original-title="" class="active">
        <input type="button" value="List" id="listview_radio" original-title="">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img id="loading" src="/core/img/loading.gif" style="display: none;">
    </form>
    <form id="choosecalendar">
        <!--<input type="button" id="today_input" value="Today"/>-->
        <button class="settings generalsettings" title="Settings"><img class="svg" src="/core/img/actions/settings.svg" alt="Settings"></button>
    </form>
    <form id="datecontrol">
        <input type="button" value="&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;" id="datecontrol_left" original-title="">
        <input type="button" value="April 2013" id="datecontrol_date" original-title="" class="hasDatepicker">
        <input type="button" value="&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;" id="datecontrol_right" original-title="">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="fullcalendar" class="fc"><div class="fc-content" style="position: relative; min-height: 1px;"><div class="fc-view fc-view-month fc-grid" style="position: relative;" unselectable="on"><table class="fc-border-separate" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr class="fc-first fc-last"><th class="fc-mon fc-widget-header fc-first" style="width: 182px;">Mon.</th><th class="fc-tue fc-widget-header" style="width: 182px;">
```

I would really appreciate any hint or help towards this.

Here is what I have

```
    <tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/index.php/apps/files</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//ul[@id='apps']/li[3]/a/img</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

---------Popup shows here ----------
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=category</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ui-id-6</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=calendar</td>
    <td>label=test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>name=accessclass</td>
    <td>label=Bizalmas</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=from</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=12</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=to</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=27</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=submitNewEvent</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//body[@id='body-user']/div[9]/div/button</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=oneweekview_radio</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=oneweekview_radio</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=onemonthview_radio</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a calendar that you can interact with using Selenium IDE. Though you should also consider Selenium Webdriver using Selenium Grid which will allow you to test your code in multiple browsers. With that said lets get you interacting with this calendar pop-up!

I recommend using an element's id (when available) and when there is no id or the id is dynamic use xpath.

For an element that does not have an id such as the input element next to Title as pictured below use the following to click it's text box.

Command `click`

Target `//input[contains(@placeholder, 'Title of the Event')]`

[image]

Image of the Selenium IDE for the image above

[image]

TIP: Use the `Find` button to see if you have specified the element correctly with your xpath. It will get highlighted.

For most of the other elements you can use their id's

Command `'click'`
Target `id=fromtime`

The biggest TIP of all that I can add is use FIREBUG! If you are using Selenium IDE you Firebug will help you immensely. You are probably already using it, but just a tip for anyone that comes across this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. what is that target exactly?  and also where do I find that Find button? Firebug is a big helper :))

Comment: Target is in the GUI version of Selenium IDE. You should be able to use it when you open your FF browser click on Tools->Selenium IDE. You will also be able to open your current IDE test from there. Target is telling Selenium which Element you want to interact with.

Comment: If you do not want to use the Selenium IDE GUI (don't know why you wouldn't) you could add a second <td> underneath your initial command and Selenium IDE will recognize that as the target. In your pasted example after ---Pop-up Shows up here--- id=category is your first target. You need a target for each command.

Comment: I am getting this error [error] Element //input[contains(@placeholder, 'ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable')] not found

Comment: Those are xpath terms. Contains means that the attribute placeholder will have at least 'az ese' somewhere in it. You could specify more or less of the placeholder element. You could also use any other attribute such as name, id, text etc.

Comment: no you are absolutely right , I am just not sure what you put in those field :(

Comment: like what do I fill up those 'az ese' with?

Comment: The contents of the placeholder of a textbox. If you want the Title's text box and are viewing the page in English use "Title of the Event" instead of "az ese" I was getting your page in another language first which I think caused the issue :D

Comment: I dont know why it changes it language :P but [error] Element //input[contains(@placeholder, 'Title of the Event')] not found

Comment: @benzo I'd seriously recommend getting away from xpath as your selector language.  There are proven time drawbacks using xpath vs. css (http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/)   The CSS alternative to your selector would be `input[placeholder*='Title of the event']`

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg I get this error still and I dont know why, I am doing everything like you are doing [picture of the screen](http://www.imgbond.com/pictures/2/386111867883825638.jpg)

Comment: @benzo Sometimes elements go out of focus so you can try re-loading the page. I am now having trouble connecting to your site, but the last thing I can say is this. You don't have to use placeholder, you can use any attribute. For example in my picture above using firebug I could have used "name='title'", type, value, size etc (though if there are other elements with the same value for the attribute selenium IDE might get them by mistake).